# Select input radio by clicking on it's parent wrapper

Tags: html, css

I've a `tile` with an `input` of type `radio`, a `label` and a `span` text below this two elements. The `input` and `label` are connected with an `id`. They should be next to each other. The `span` should be directly below the `label`. This works so far and my layout matches. If I `click` on the `input` or on the `label`, the `radio` gets `selected`. Now what I'd like to do is, to `select` the `radio` by clicking on the `tile`, no mather where. So every click on the `tile` should select my `radio`. I would like to solve this with pure `HTML/CSS` without using `JS`, if possible. The only idea I had, is to give `position: relative;` to the `radio` and `position: absolute;` to the `radio__wrap` and the `label` and make them have `width/height` of `100%`, so I can pull over the `label` over the whole `tile`. This idea crashed my layout (hard do position the `span` correctly). Is there a way to solve this by using pure `HTML/CSS`. Below is my snippet:

```css
.tile {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.tile__wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.radio {
  padding: 24px 16px 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.radio__wrap {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.radio__label {
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.radio__text {
  padding-left: 24px;
  display: block;
}

.tile--clickable .radio__wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.tile--clickable .radio__label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <div class="tile__wrap">
    <div class="radio">
      <div class="radio__wrap">
        <input class="radio__input" id="radio01" type="radio">
        <label class="radio__label" for="radio01">I'm the label</label>
      </div>
      <span class="radio__text">I'm the text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any attempt to achieve this without Javascript will be very hacky. Why can't you simply use Javascript for this very simple task?

Comment: Just wrap your radio button inside label

Comment: I managed to tho something like I'd searched: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/EeBwNZ